# UIPickerView UIToolbar tintColor changing randomly

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I have a strange problem in my pickerView toolbar. It shows differently in simulator and real device. I configured my `toolBar` `barTintColor` for background color and `tintColor` for button text colors.

```
// Configuring PickerViews
    private func configurePickerViews(pickerView: UIPickerView, textField: UITextField) {
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barTintColor = DesignSettings().vetMappColor
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Seç", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "choosePickerMethod")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Vazgeç", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPickerMethod")

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    textField.inputView = pickerView
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        return citiesDatabase.getCities().count
    }else{
        if let city = cityTextField.text {
            return citiesDatabase.getTowns(city: city).count
        }
        return 0
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        cityTextField.text = citiesDatabase.getCities()[row]
        return citiesDatabase.getCities()[row]
    } else {
        if let city = cityTextField.text {
            townTextField.text = citiesDatabase.getTowns(city: city)[row]
            return citiesDatabase.getTowns(city: city)[row]
        }
        return nil
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        cityTextField.text = citiesDatabase.getCities()[row]
    } else {
        if let city = cityTextField.text {
            townTextField.text = citiesDatabase.getTowns(city: city)[row]
        }
    }
}

// Changing Picker View Text Color Delegate
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        let citiesData = citiesDatabase.getCities()[row]
        let citiesTitle = NSAttributedString(string: citiesData, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:DesignSettings().vetMappColor])
        return citiesTitle
    }else{
        if let city = cityTextField.text {
            let townData = citiesDatabase.getTowns(city: city)[row]
            let townTitle = NSAttributedString(string: townData, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:DesignSettings().vetMappColor])
            return townTitle
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

These are the screenshots from the device & simulator. Simulator is showing fine but device is changing colors.

**Simulator:**

[image: Simulator Screen Shot]

**Device:**

[image: Real Device Screen Shot]